# Identify Isotonic list or not

Tags: python, list

I am working on identifying if the list is Isotonic or not.

I have this:

```
true_list = [5,4,3,1,1]
true_list1=list[::-1]

f_list = [5,4,9,1,1]
f_list1=f_list[::-1]

def isMonotonic(item):
  if len(item)==1:
    return True
  else:
    if all(item[x]<=item[x+1]  for x in range(0,len(item)-1) or 
           item[x]>=item[x+1] for x in range(0,len(item)-1) ):
        return True
    else:
      return False

print(true_list)
print(isMonotonic(true_list))
print(true_list1)
print(isMonotonic(true_list1))
print(f_list)
print(isMonotonic(f_list))
print(f_list1)
print(isMonotonic(f_list1))
```

**I don't understand why for `true_list` it returns `False`**

For `f_list` and `f_list1` : It should be `False` and it is `False`.

Please advise.

Thank You

Comment: You need two separate `all()` calls with `or` between them. The way you have it now doesn't work the way you think it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because your `if` condition is incorrect. The `all` would return `True` if all conditions in it are `True`.

What you need is "(all numbers are decreasing monotonically) OR (all numbers are increasing monotonically)"

```
true_list = [5,4,3,1,1]
true_list1=true_list[::-1]

f_list = [5,4,9,1,1]
f_list1=f_list[::-1]

def isMonotonic(item):
  if len(item)==1:
    return True
  else:
    if (all(item[x]<=item[x+1]  for x in range(0,len(item)-1)) or 
           all(item[x]>=item[x+1] for x in range(0,len(item)-1))) :
        return True
    else:
      return False

print(true_list)
print(isMonotonic(true_list))
print(true_list1)
print(isMonotonic(true_list1))
print(f_list)
print(isMonotonic(f_list))
print(f_list1)
print(isMonotonic(f_list1))
```

outputs -

```
[5, 4, 3, 1, 1]
True
[1, 1, 3, 4, 5]
True
[5, 4, 9, 1, 1]
False
[1, 1, 9, 4, 5]
False
```

Comment: Thank You. I did not knew how those ( ) worked earlier. Now it does.